# How can I print a pdf document from Xamarin.Forms UWP?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, printing, uwp

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that supports only UWP. I cannot find a way to print a pdf document. Whatever I have seen on the web, for some reason doesn't work for me. E.g. I tried

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8767/how-to-print-pdf-documents-in-xamarin-forms-platform

It lets me print, but the preview in the print dialog never shows up, and the progress indicator just keeps rotating forever.

I also tried http://zawayasoft.com/2018/03/13/uwp-print-pdf-files-silently-without-print-dialog/
This gives me errors that I cannot fix.

So I wonder if there is something else that would actually work. Maybe something newer than what I have tried (I use VS 2017). Printing without the printing dialog would be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

I used a very dirty hack to do that!

What I had to do was to try to print the image version of the pdf (I did the conversion in backend) and then used the following DependencyInjection:

Inside my Print class in UWP project:

```
class Print : IPrint
    {
        void IPrint.Print(byte[] content)
        {
            Print_UWP printing = new Print_UWP();
            printing.PrintUWpAsync(content);
        }
    }
```

and the class responsible for printing in uwp:

```
 public class Print_UWP
    {
        PrintManager printmgr = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
        PrintDocument PrintDoc = null;
        PrintDocument printDoc;
        PrintTask Task = null;
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image ViewToPrint = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image();

        public Print_UWP()
        {

            printmgr.PrintTaskRequested += Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested;
        }

        public async void PrintUWpAsync(byte[] imageData)
        {
            int i = 0;

            while (i < 5)
            {
                try
                {
                    BitmapImage biSource = new BitmapImage();
                    using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
                    {
                        await stream.WriteAsync(imageData.AsBuffer());
                        stream.Seek(0);
                        await biSource.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                    }

                    ViewToPrint.Source = biSource;
                    if (PrintDoc != null)
                    {
                        printDoc.GetPreviewPage -= PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage;
                        printDoc.Paginate -= PrintDoc_Paginate;
                        printDoc.AddPages -= PrintDoc_AddPages;
                    }

                    this.printDoc = new PrintDocument();
                    try
                    {
                        printDoc.GetPreviewPage += PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage;
                        printDoc.Paginate += PrintDoc_Paginate;
                        printDoc.AddPages += PrintDoc_AddPages;

                        bool showprint = await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    }

                    //  printmgr = null;
                    // printDoc = null;
                    // Task = null;
                    PrintDoc = null;
                    GC.Collect();
                    printmgr.PrintTaskRequested -= Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested;
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    i++;
                }

            }
        }

        private void Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            var deff = args.Request.GetDeferral();
            Task = args.Request.CreatePrintTask("Invoice", OnPrintTaskSourceRequested);

            deff.Complete();

        }

        async void OnPrintTaskSourceRequested(PrintTaskSourceRequestedArgs args)
        {
            var def = args.GetDeferral();
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                args.SetSource(printDoc.DocumentSource);
            });
            def.Complete();
        }

        private void PrintDoc_AddPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
        {
            printDoc.AddPage(ViewToPrint);
            printDoc.AddPagesComplete();
        }

        private void PrintDoc_Paginate(object sender, PaginateEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintTaskOptions opt = Task.Options;
            printDoc.SetPreviewPageCount(1, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
        }

        private void PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            printDoc.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, ViewToPrint);
        }

    }
```

Please note that this is not a perfect solution and sometimes it crashes without actually being able to trace the exception (which is really strange) so I am sure there must be better answers even though it does the job.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Of course, it would be better to avoid crashing. I will wait, and if I don't get anything better, like you said, I may use yours. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried this solution. Unfortunately, it gives me an exception:  The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)   at CustomerKiosk.UWP.Services.Print_UWP.<PrintUWpAsync>d__6.MoveNext()

Any idea?

Comment: Have you set up the DependecyInjection properly?

Comment: I think so. The execution comes to await biSource.SetSourceAsync(stream); and never reaches the next line. I believe the exception happens somewhere there.

Comment: What's your XF version?

Comment: It is 3.4.0.1008975